# Any way I can mock/shadow MediaStore for Android Instumentation testing

Tags: robolectric, android-uiautomator

I am writing Android Instrumentation tests with UiAutomator2 these days.
I want to pick a specific video with my media video picker before testing.

My app uses `MediaStore` and there is no way found I can load only a certain video.

So far, I come up with idea that delete `DCIM` directory, push certain video to `DCIM` directory and force scan it.
However, this takes much time.

I wander if there is better way than this.